# C++ stoi equivalent in SQL Server's T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, order-by, cast

I'm looking for something I can use in Microsot SQL Server that would act the same way the stoi function in C++ acts.  Specifically, I'm looking to be able to grab numerics at the beginning of the string, and ignore non-numerics afterwards.  I need this to sort the following strings and need them to show up in the following order:

> 99ABC
>   123ABCD
>   ABC
>   DEFGH

So I was thinking if I had something like STOI, I can do:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (ISNUMERIC(LEFT(TEXT, 1))) THEN STOI(TEXT) ELSE 999999 END, TEXT
```

I can precompute the results of STOI (or the results of the above CASE statement) and store into an extra INT column nightly.  So I don't really care about real-time performance.  I guess I'm just looking for a way without having to check all the chars of the string:

```
DECLARE @numEnd INT = 0 
WHILE (ISNUMERIC(LEFT(TEXT, @numEnd)) BEGIN
     SET @numEnd = @numEnd + 1 
END
DECLARE @stoi INT = CAST(LEFT(TEXT, @numEnd) AS INT)
```

Comment: What is STOI's result if the string doesn't start with a number?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin zero I believe, or null.  But since I need non-numerics at the end, that why I added the ELSE 99999 at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(32)

SET @Test = '99ABC 123ABCD ABC DEFGH'

DECLARE @stoi INT = TRY_CONVERT(INT, LEFT(LTRIM(@Test), PATINDEX('%[^0123456789]%', LTRIM(@Test + ';')) - 1))

SELECT @stoi
```

> 99